# How can a directory at the same time be a file?

Tags: python

I was working with the python os module and confronted some obstacles regarding the symbolic path thing..

```
linkdir = os.path.dirname(filepath)
if not os.path.isdir(linkdir):
    if os.path.exists(linkdir):
        os.unlink(linkdir)
    os.makedirs(linkdir)
```

this is the code that i had problem fully understanding. Accrording to the explanation on the book, it means:

If I enter the if clause, this means the directory either does not exist or is a plain file.
In the case, it is the latter, so it will be erased. Finally, the target directory is created.

However i do not exactly understand how the directory(linkdir) could be a plain file. I tried to google it but just got an answer : 'Because it is the symbolic link'. I honestly do not get it with such short answer... Would you be kind enough to explain it to me in an understandable fashion?

Comment: which line you not understand from above code ?

Comment: 'symbolic link' means a shortcut, and it is a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code tries to clear the way for a directory being created. The value in `filepath` is *just a string*. It isn't actually connected to anything on the filesystem, but you cannot just create a directory without checking if there isn't anything in the way first.

If you have the value `/foo/bar/spam.html` in `filepath`, the code does this:

- extract the directory portion of that path, `/foo/bar`. This is still just a string, nothing really to do with the actual file system.
- Test if `/foo/bar` is an actual directory on your filesystem with `os.path.isdir()`. If there is an existing directory at that location, you are done, mission accomplished.
- If it is *not* a directory, then test if `/foo/bar` *exists at all*. We already discounted that it is a directory, so if `/foo/bar` exists *anyway* it must be *something else*. Usually that means it is a file. The code then will delete whatever is there to make way for the directory.

This doesn't have all that much to do with symbolic links; `/foo/bar` could be a pre-existing symbolic link too, but that doesn't really matter here. All that matters is that whatever actually exists on your filesystem at `/foo/bar` better be a directory already, otherwise it needs to be removed before you can create a directory there.

Comment: Thanks. This really clears my thoughts. However, i just have one more question. Is there actually a chance of a file named '/foo/bar' existing in my computer? I just cannot imagine having a file named '/foo/bar'... Sorry if you think it is asking the same question over again.

Comment: @heesubahn: `foo` and `bar` are [popular example values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar). You didn't share a value for `filepath` so I made one up. It depends entirely on the context of the program what the actual path would look like.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: Thankyou, and i do know that you just made out an example. But since i'm so newbie to the computer world, to me,the fact that  'something/something/'(Which we typically think of as a directory, because there are no .txt,.jpeg... etc) could sometimes be treated as a file is so strange.. but Thanks so much anyway!!!!

Comment: @heesubahn: extensions are just a convention. Files don't *have* to have an extension to be a file.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: I just tried to make one of them without extensions and it worked. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score -1):

Because os.path.dirname(filepath) only splits the string "filepath" into head and tail according to slash.
It doesn't check whether the head is an existing directory.

For example, we hava a file named "a" in the working directory.

(1) the code

```
os.path.dirname("a/a")
```

returns "a".

(2) however, it is false if we check it via isdir

(3) it returns true if we check it via isfile